# SQL Server replication with subscriber doesn't know about the publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, merge-replication

I have a case where many SQL Server instances need to be merged and centralized in one master database.

This needs to be near real-time solution. After looking around in Google, I've found that transactional replication can do the trick.

The problem is that I have (n) publisher databases, and they don't even have static IPs. I had the impression that push replication will be enough to send the data to the centralized database without knowing about the publisher connection, but it seems like I was wrong.

My question is: How can I set up an solution to merge/replicate multiple publisher databases which don't have static IPs, and might suffer frequent outage from the network, all that in near real-time?

Comment: if all servers in the same place you can setup private network between all servers to sync.

Comment: They will be connected using public network.

Comment: if your machine using DHCP, you can use VPN to connect to each other, but this is a costly solution, since moving a huge data over Internet need a good Internet connection

Answer (score 1):

A VPN connection can be used to connect to each other. But moving a huge data over Internet is done using DHCP connection, And may be slower depending on your internet connection.